# ggplot2, geom_text and order

Tags: r, ggplot2

The issue I'm facing is very simple.

I'm plotting 3 types of data in a bar graph with the percentages on the Y axis, and coloring each group using another column from my dataframe.

The graph looks like this :

[image: graph]

generated with

```
ggplot(cleaned_data, aes(x = Engine, fill = Errorcat)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  scale_fill_discrete("Events", breaks = c("Ok", "Waiting", "Error")) +
  labs(y = "")
```

The data have been factored like this :
    cleaned_data$Errorcat <- factor(cleaned_data$Errorcat, levels = c("Error", "Ok", "Waiting"))

I just want to display the corresponding percentages in the middle of each bin. So I went back in and just added a geom_text call, like this :

```
ggplot(cleaned_data, aes(x = Engine, fill = Errorcat)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)) - 0.5*    (((..count..)/sum(..count..))) ,
                label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25, check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  scale_fill_discrete("Events", breaks = c("Ok", "Waiting", "Error")) +
  labs(y = "")
```

It produces this :

[image: Graph 2]

The figures are right, only their respectives Y coordinates are not in the correct order. As you can see, the 45% for instance is the "top" figure, while it should correspond to the blue, not the green. from bottom to top, I think geom_text is displaying red/blue/green while I want just like the bars red/green/blue.

I can't seem to understand how I can do that nor why it's not doing it right away. The end goal is to have specific color assigned to the Errorcat. I want Ok to be green, waiting to be blue and Error to be red. And the legend I want Ok on top then waiting then Error.

If anyone would be kind enough to explain what I am missing... Thank you !

Comment: Is the underlying order of your factors in 'Events' different to the order in which you've specified to `breaks`

Comment: It's indeed different. 
`cleaned_data$Errorcat <- factor(cleaned_data$Errorcat, levels = c("Error", "Ok", "Waiting"))`
I want specifically Ok to be green, waiting blue and error red, and the legend to be ordered as it is, ie Ok first then waiting then error.

Comment: In ggplot2 2.2.0 you'd need something like `geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", check_overlap = TRUE, position = position_stack(vjust = .5))`

Comment: Using your suggestion like this : `ggplot(cleaned_data, aes(x = Engine, fill = Errorcat)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))),
            stat = "count", check_overlap = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  scale_fill_discrete("Events", breaks = c("Ok", "Waiting", "Error")) +
  labs(y = "")`
is getting me close to my goal, except that the vjust is not taken into account (unused argument). I don't know why.

Comment: Erratum : I've just updated all my packages and it now works !! I'll post as the answer. Thanks all for the support, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the comments above, the following code is producing all the labels at the right spot, centered in each bin :

```
ggplot(cleaned_data, aes(x = Engine, fill = Errorcat)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))),
            stat = "count", check_overlap = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  scale_fill_discrete("Events", breaks = c("Ok", "Waiting", "Error")) +
  labs(y = "")
```

Thanks everyone.